# how to read all the hyperlinks in the word doc and click on the 1st hyperlink in word doc automatically

Tags: python, hyperlink, ms-word

I'd like to search a Word 2007 file (.docx) for a hyperlink i.e if there are so many hyperlinks it should read all the hyperlinks and then click on first hyperlink automatically

Is there a way from Python to search for hyperlink and open the first hyperlink automatically?

Answer (score 2):

For the search of hyperlinks you can use regexp (`re` module) something like:

```
re.find_all("www\..+\..{1,3}", text_data
```

Assuming `text_data` contains the text from the document.

After that you can use `urllib` to open the page you want, and i would use `beautifulsoup` from `bs4` parse its content

Comment: Sorry i can give you a more detailed answer, but if you provide some samples about how the hyperlinks look, or show us your code we will be able to give you a better solution!